# selecting the data between two date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to select the price between two date (star date and end date). In my database i have fixed price like this:

```
2013-05-01 to 2013-05-31  price: 300
2013-06-01 to 2013-06-30  price: 200
2013-07-01 to 2013-07-01  price: 250
```

I user selects any date between these 3 i am able to generate result by doing

```
sdate>='2013-05-01' 
AND edate <='2013-05-31'`.
```

But if a user selects date `2013-05-28 to 2013-06-03` then it should two days price (300) for may month and 3 days price (200) from the month june. 
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Your original WHERE statement should still work, maybe theres something more in the query we aren't shown?  Such as TOP 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 select price from tablename where sdate >= '2013-05-01' and edate <= '2013-05-31'
```

Comment: but my column name is sdate and edate.

Comment: Are you sure that Date sdate >= etc is valid sql?

Answer (score 1):

if user enter date for two different months then your select query will return two prices. assume **select price from tb_demo where sdate>='2013-06-01' and edate<='2013-07-31'** this will return two prices which is stored into resultset.

After that by using while loop you can easy print those price.If u want to print month name also then use array and print that name.

Answer (score 0):

Please Before positing Use search...

[SQL query to select dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)