# Check if a time is between two times (time DataType)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that has a column "Created" as a datetime.

I'm trying to query to check if the time for the Created value is between two times.

The Created datetime for the first row is '2013-07-01 00:00:00.000' (Midnight) and I'm trying to query for items with a time between 11PM and 7AM.

```
select *
from MyTable
where CAST(Created as time) between '23:00:00' and '06:59:59'
```

But no results are returned.

Do I need to convert my times to datetimes?

Comment: similar question with an example [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: Yes between 11PM and 7AM the next day

Comment: Actually, it doesn't have to be between two days. I have a table for employee shifts. Shift 3 has a start time of 23:00:00 (11PM) and an end time of 06:59:59. Both of these are stored as the 'time' data type.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: between 23h and 7h at the same day makes not much sense since the first time is later than the second and the result set is always empty.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I didn't want to get into an argument about this, so I erased my post. My logic told me that it was not important. In this case i was right, however i see other senarios where your question makes sense

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I suspect you want to check that it's *after* 11pm or *before* 7am:

```
select *
from MyTable
where CAST(Created as time) >= '23:00:00' 
   or CAST(Created as time) < '07:00:00'
```

Comment: Good answer but this only applies to SQL server 2008 and newer

Comment: You also need to be very careful if you are looking to group together items based on the date.  If something was packed this morning at 6 AM, it would group with something else packed tonight at 11:30 PM.  If you needed to group together based on date, I would suggest either adding an hour or subtracting seven hours, then performing a calculation, as necessary.

Comment: what if you want to check between 07:00 and 23:00 in that case this logic will not work and since time range will vary cant depend on this

Comment: @George: Then it would be a different situation, requiring different code. It should be easy to detect which situation is applicable though.

Comment: @JonSkeet 'thanks a billion' <3. I've added case if start time is greater than end time and vs. much love, much appreciated, ur the hero

Comment: See @Manuel's answer below to handle more scenarios: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53320415/269123

Answer (score 15):

```
select *
from MyTable
where CAST(Created as time) not between '07:00' and '22:59:59 997'
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a very similar problem and want to share my solution

Given this table (all MySQL 5.6):

```sql
create table DailySchedule
(
  id         int auto_increment primary key,
  start_time time not null,
  stop_time  time not null
);
```

Select all rows where a given time `x (hh:mm:ss)` is between start and stop time. Including the next day.

Note: replace `NOW()` with the any time `x` you like

```sql
SELECT id
FROM DailySchedule
WHERE
  (start_time < stop_time AND NOW() BETWEEN start_time AND stop_time)
  OR
  (stop_time < start_time AND NOW() < start_time AND NOW() < stop_time)
  OR
  (stop_time < start_time AND NOW() > start_time)
```

**Results**

Given

```
  id: 1, start_time: 10:00:00, stop_time: 15:00:00
  id: 2, start_time: 22:00:00, stop_time: 12:00:00
```

- Selected rows with `NOW = 09:00:00`: `2`
- Selected rows with `NOW = 14:00:00`: `1`
- Selected rows with `NOW = 11:00:00`: `1,2`
- Selected rows with `NOW = 20:00:00`: nothing

Answer (score 1):

This should also work (even in SQL-Server 2005):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE Created >= DATEADD(hh,23,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, Created - 1), 0))
  AND Created <  DATEADD(hh,7,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, Created), 0))
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12ec9/14/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE as
(
SELECT CAST(ShiftStart AS DATETIME) AS ShiftStart, 
CASE WHEN ShiftStart > ShiftEnd THEN CAST(ShiftEnd AS DATETIME) +1
ELSE CAST(ShiftEnd AS DATETIME) END AS ShiftEnd
FROM **TABLE_NAME**
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE 
CAST('11:00:00' AS DATETIME) BETWEEN ShiftStart AND ShiftEnd -- Start of Shift
OR CAST('23:00:00' AS DATETIME) BETWEEN ShiftStart AND ShiftEnd -- End of Shift
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a table which stores the shift details

[image]

Please check the SQL queries to generate table and finding the schedule based on an input(time)

**Declaring the Table variable**

```
declare @MyShiftTable table(MyShift int,StartTime time,EndTime time)
```

**Adding values to Table variable**

```
insert into @MyShiftTable select 1,'01:17:40.3530000','02:17:40.3530000'
insert into @MyShiftTable select 2,'09:17:40.3530000','03:17:40.3530000'
insert into @MyShiftTable select 3,'10:17:40.3530000','18:17:40.3530000'
```

**Creating another table variable with an additional field named "Flag"**

```
declare @Temp table(MyShift int,StartTime time,EndTime time,Flag int)
```

**Adding values to temporary table with swapping the start and end time**

```
insert into @Temp 
select 
  MyShift, 
  case when (StartTime > EndTime) then EndTime else StartTime end, 
  case when (StartTime > EndTime) then StartTime else EndTime end, 
  case when (StartTime > EndTime) then 1 else 0 end 
from 
  @MyShiftTable
```

**Creating input variable to find the Shift**

```
declare @time time=convert(time,'10:12:40.3530000')
```

**Query to find the shift corresponding to the time supplied**

```
select 
  myShift 
from 
  @Temp 
where 
  (
    @time between StartTime 
    and EndTime 
    and Flag = 0
  ) 
  or (
    @time not between StartTime 
    and EndTime 
    and Flag = 1
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  * 
from 
  dbMaster oMaster 
where 
  (
    (
      CAST(
        GETDATE() as time
      )
    ) between (
      CAST(oMaster.DateFrom as time)
    ) 
    and (
      CAST(oMaster.DateTo as time)
    )
  )
```

> Please check this

Answer (score -1):

Should be AND instead of OR

```
select *
from MyTable
where CAST(Created as time) >= '23:00:00' 
   AND CAST(Created as time) < '07:00:00'
```

Comment: There is no `OR` in the question?

Comment: A time can never be both less than `7:00` and greater than `23:00`, so the `AND` results in 0 records being returned no matter what.