# SQL Check if available between times

Tags: mysql, datetime, between

I'm trying to code a system that let's user book items.
Items can't be booked twice. So if an item is unavailable i would like to know that by using SQL.

I've got a database with the following fields
id,item, start (datetime), end (datetime)

A user will try to book an item from "01-01-2016 09:00" till "01-01-2016-22:00". But there is already a row where start is "01-01-2016 11:00" and end is "01-01-2016 16:00". So.. The item isn't available.

How can i do that in SQL?

Now i am using this:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE (`start` between '$start' and '$end') AND (`item` = $id)
```

Then i look if the number of rows is higher then 0. If so, the item is unavailable. This works.. but not when the start time is BEFORE the new start time.

I'm hoping that my explanation is clear... Having a hard time dealing with this issue because i can't get the facts straight.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407481/check-if-a-time-is-between-two-times-time-datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is okey actually that `start` could be before the new start time. But you have also check if the `end` is also in the between interval. Also for the comment case, you have to check if there is smaller interval.
Expand your query following way:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE ((`start` between '$start' and '$end') OR (`end` between '$start' and '$end') OR (`start` >= '$start' and `end` <=  '$end')) AND (`item` = $id)
```

Comment: This will not work when the row is start "20:00:00" and end is "23:00:00" and $start is "21:00:00" and $end is "22:00:00".

Comment: Sorry. You need one more condition. See updated query.

Comment: Thx! First i thought your edit didn't work but i made a typo! THX!