# SQL Select Statement with where, AND, OR not working correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello everyone i have the following row as a sample in my table

```
id      shop_id     start_time      end_time
1       21          10:00           11:00
```

and i want to check whether start_time and end_time exist in table or not 
I am using following query but not working correctly, Where i am wrong ?

```
select * 
  from usr_booking 
 where shop_id='21' 
   and start_time between '10:10:00' and '11:01:00' 
    or end_time   between '10:10:00' and '11:01:00'
```

Comment: The syntax in your query has a problem, yet despite that the single record you showed us in fact should be matched.  What is the exact problem?

Comment: Try using >, < operators. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407481/check-if-a-time-is-between-two-times-time-datatype

Comment: Are `start_time` and `end_time` actually date types? Or is the column another type?

Comment: and What does the query return ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clearly separate the checks on the `shop_id` and the time ranges:

```
SELECT *
FROM usr_booking
WHERE
    shop_id = 21 AND
    (start_time BETWEEN '10:10:00' AND '11:01:00' OR
     end_time BETWEEN '10:10:00' AND '11:01:00');
```

The `AND` operator in MySQL has higher precedence than the `OR` operator.  So, your current query is actually evaluating as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM usr_booking
WHERE
    (shop_id = 21 AND
     start_time BETWEEN '10:10:00' AND '11:01:00') OR
     end_time BETWEEN '10:10:00' AND '11:01:00';
```

Clearly, this is not the same logic as you what you probably intended.

Comment: this wont work if start time is 14:00 and end time is 09:00 (i.e next day)
any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make groups in such type of queries

```
select * from usr_booking where shop_id='21' AND ((start_time between '10:10:00' and '11:01:00') OR (end_time between '10:10:00' and '11:01:00'))
```

Add the extra brackets make groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM usr_booking 
Where shop_id='21' AND start_time BETWEEN '10:10:00' AND '11:01:00' 
AND end_time BETWEEN '10:10:00' AND '11:01:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM usr_booking WHERE shop_id=21 AND (start_time BETWEEN '10:10:00' AND '11:01:00') OR (end_time BETWEEN '10:10:00' AND '11:01:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are given the times '10:10:00' and '11:01:00' and you want to know if anything overlaps with that period, then the logic is:

```
select b.* 
from usr_booking 
where shop_id = 21 and -- do not use single quotes for numeric constants (assuming `shop_id` is a number
      end_time > '10:10:00' and
      start_time < '11:01:00';
```

For overlapping intervals, `between` is not appropriate.