# Select value from database with date condition

Tags: java, database, date, jtable, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox that contains months ( september , july ... )
And one jTable
And  a table (Bills) in database that contains ( Id bill , date , products ..)

I want that when a choose a value from jComboBox like september it give me all products in september .

And the date format is like     2014/May/27     14:31:04

and I tried this code but it didnt work because in java i cant use :

```
String sql1 = "select Products from Bills where Date LIKE "?????+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+*" ";
```

(it give an error and I can't compile)

The code :

```
try

{

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

    Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);

    String sql1 = "select Products from Bills where Date LIKE "?????+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+* " ";

    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql1);

    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) pst.executeQuery(sql1);

    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

}
catch( Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

}
```

Comment: best practise , sout the query, and check in the Database, and continue further

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql1 = "select Products from Bills where Date LIKE "?????+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+* " ";
```

Why is like that ?? What are the questions marks?

Should be like that:

```
String sql1 = "select Products from Bills where Date LIKE '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+ "'";
```

Comment: yes I know but the date format is 2014/May/27     14:31:04 , and date type is string and the problem is that the conditon is :  String sql1 = "select Products from Bills where Date LIKE ????'"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+ "'*  ";
 but didnt work

Comment: Well.. You should format your date with SimpleDateFormat 
Here is a nice tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/
Something like that: SimpleDateFormat("mm");

In addition after you do that your string will be:
"select Products from Bills where Date LIKE '????/"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+ "*'";

Something like that.. But i would suggest to use preparedStatment
Here is a nice tutorial
http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Comment: Well it cannot work, because the SQL wildcard is a '%' not a '*', so Your query should be "select Products from Bills where Date LIKE '%"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+ "%' "; ... but again, not fuddle sql together, use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples and pears. Dates only can be compared to matching types. So if the column is of type date, you cannot use a String comparison on it (which LIKE actually is).

Your prepared statement should look sorta

```
...
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss").parse(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT PRODUCTS FROM BILLS WHERE DATE = :dv");
pst.setDate("dv", d);
...
```

Otherwise, You will run into trouble creating invalid SQL or - even worse - make Your software beeing endangered by SQL injection (security issue).

EDIT : Date algorithms always come up with the special flavour of the database vendor. You should check the DB manual for proper operands. For example, DB2 allows inline casting a date without any operand. See [SQL query to select dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates) for some example.

Comment: date column is of type string , and date fromat :                     2014/May/27 14:31:04  , for this reason i used LIKE " ?????+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+ * "

Comment: ok, then forget about the date cast - although it is no good design to use the wrong type ;-) A "DATE LIKE :dv" works if you simply make the value '%Sep%'