# How can I select dates in SQL server to show?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way for me to show dates using a select statement in sql dates from to To?
Like if I select the date Jan. 15 2013 as from and Jan. 20, 2013 as To the query will show the following:

```
    DATE
 2013/01/15  12:00
 2013/01/16  12:00
 2013/01/16  12:00
 2013/01/17  12:00
 2013/01/18  12:00
 2013/01/19  12:00
 2013/01/20  12:00
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be to write something as:

```
DECLARE @from DATE, @to DATE;
SELECT @from = '2013-01-15' , @to = '2013-01-20';

  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @from)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @from, @to)+1) ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
      CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
  ) AS x(n);
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/JGLNP57037) here.

Comment: I am not sure if he has the permission to access `sys` but it's good solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use `BETWEEN...AND`:

```
SELECT DateCol
FROM TableName
WHERE DateCol BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
ORDER BY DateCol
```

Comment: what if I don't have a column that have dates on it? Do it still possible for me to get dates?

Comment: It depends what data type in field. Ex. if you have varchar u can use convert to datetime and than use between as @raging said. http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187928%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: You can use cast function but dates should be in correct format . try select cast(data_col as datetime) from table_1

Answer (score 1):

Next solution. I think more intuitive

```
declare @table table (d datetime)

declare @start datetime = '2014-01-01'
declare @stop datetime = '2014-01-21'

while @start <= @stop
begin
  insert into @table (d)
  values (@start)

  set @start = DATEADD(day, 1, @start)
end

select * from @table
```