# php get exact report from date between report from db

Tags: php, mysql, between

```
$query1 = "SELECT *FROM sales where date between '$date' and '$date1'";

            $result = mysql_query($query1);

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Result:

please check below link

Date from 01-06-2014 to 27-06-2014 
[enter link description here](http://www.chltech.in/table_date.png)

get proper result of select date month year, need proper result with day month year.
Its urgent

if some one select from 01-06-2014 to 27-06-2014  result should show between dates any entry.. but its should showing some other date range which is not selected..

hope you understand

Comment: Sidenote: `*FROM` space that out a bit. Plus, get rid of the LIKE.

Comment: I think there are other questions on this, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: From a logic perspective, you are not searching for dates 'like between' A and B. You're searching for dates 'between' A and B...

Comment: sorry i didn't used like.. but event reference link its the same.. i am not getting solution..

Comment: What type of field is date?

Comment: Date field is varchar(100)

Comment: i got solution now i change the field with date and now its working fine.. thanks dud.. but i want to change the format with dd-mm-yy in to mysql, please help on this..