# How to get first in and last out of attendance system in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table `IOData` as shown below

```
   E Name   Date            Time    Status
   A1   08/06/14    19:36:10.00 Entry
   A1   08/06/14    19:36:16.00 Exit
   A1   08/06/14    19:36:18.00 Entry
   A1   08/07/14    00:26:39.00 Exit
   A1   08/07/14    00:38:36.00 Entry
   A1   08/07/14    02:41:14.00 Exit
   B1   08/07/14    19:12:29.00 Entry
   B1   08/08/14    04:14:28.00 Exit
   B1   08/08/14    04:14:31.00 Entry
   B1   08/08/14    04:14:33.00 Exit
   C1   08/06/14    19:26:10.00 Entry
   C1   08/06/14    19:36:16.00 Exit
   C1   08/06/14    19:36:50.00 Entry
   C1   08/06/14    23:06:28.00 Exit
```

I want the output as first Entry and Last Exit as show below

```
 EName    Date        Time      Status
   A1    08/06/14   19:36:10.00 Entry
   A1    08/07/14   02:41:14.00 Exit
   B1    08/07/14   19:12:29.00 Entry
   B1    08/08/14   04:14:33.00 Exit
   C1    08/06/14   19:26:10.00 Entry
   C1    08/06/14   23:06:28.00 Exit
```

I have no Idea to perform this task. I have googled but no help. Please do the needful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DECLARE @IOData AS TABLE(Name VARCHAR(MAX), [Date] DATE, [Time] TIME, [Status] VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @IOData(Name, [Date], [Time], [Status])
VALUES 
   ('A1',   '08/06/14',   '19:36:10.00', 'Entry'),
   ('A1',   '08/06/14',   '19:36:16.00', 'Exit'), 
   ('A1',   '08/06/14',   '19:36:18.00', 'Entry'),
   ('A1',   '08/07/14',   '00:26:39.00', 'Exit'),
   ('A1',   '08/07/14',   '00:38:36.00', 'Entry'),
   ('A1',   '08/07/14',   '02:41:14.00', 'Exit'),
   ('B1',   '08/07/14',   '19:12:29.00', 'Entry'),
   ('B1',   '08/08/14',   '04:14:28.00', 'Exit'),
   ('B1',   '08/08/14',   '04:14:31.00', 'Entry'),
   ('B1',   '08/08/14',   '04:14:33.00', 'Exit'),
   ('C1',   '08/06/14',   '19:26:10.00', 'Entry'),
   ('C1',   '08/06/14',   '19:36:16.00', 'Exit'),
   ('C1',   '08/06/14',   '19:36:50.00', 'Entry'),
   ('C1',   '08/06/14',   '23:06:28.00', 'Exit')`

;WITH _FirstEntries AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT FirstEntries.* FROM @IOData AS ID
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT TOP 1 * 
         FROM @IOData AS ID2 
         WHERE [Status] = 'Entry'
         AND ID2.Name = ID.Name
         ORDER BY ID2.[Date] ASC
         , ID2.[Time] ASC) AS FirstEntries
    )
, _LastExits AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT LastExit.* FROM @IOData AS ID
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT TOP 1 * 
         FROM @IOData AS ID2 
         WHERE [Status] = 'Exit'
         AND ID2.Name = ID.Name
         ORDER BY ID2.[Date] DESC
         , ID2.[Time] DESC) AS LastExit
)
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM _FirstEntries
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM _LastExits
) AS ResultUnSorted
ORDER BY Name, [Status]

Comment: Thanks Miezke. Its very helpful for me. I have another query regarding this. How to give date range in where condition if I want to filter the data by date.

Comment: You mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT EName,
           Date,
           Time,
           Status,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EName ORDER BY Date, Time) AS FirstRn,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EName ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC) AS LastRn
    FROM   IOData 
)
SELECT   EName,
         Date,
         Time,
         Status
FROM     MyCTE  
WHERE    FirstRn = 1 
         OR LastRn = 1
ORDER BY EName,
         Date,
         Time
```

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c24e8/2)**