# SQLite database - select the data between two dates?

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

I want to select my data by date - from a date until another date, so I have this query,

```
SELECT * FROM mytalbe WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-10-09' AND '2014-10-10'
```

But this query only return the data in `'2014-10-09'`, excluding the data in `'2014-10-10'`, unless I change the query to this below,

```
SELECT * FROM mytalbe WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-10-09' AND '2014-10-11'
```

This is not an ideal solution. How can I select the data including the data in `'2014-10-10'`?

**NOTE:**

I think my problem is different from other duplicate questions becos,

1. My date type is `TEXT`.
2. I need to select the date's data without its time.
3. It is an SQLite database.

My sample data:

```
    sid     nid timestamp   date    
1   20748   5   1412881193  2014-10-09 14:59:53 
2   20749   5   1412881300  2014-10-09 15:01:40 
3   20750   5   1412881360  2014-10-09 15:02:40
```

Comment: what field type is "date"?

Comment: `'2014-10-11'` means midnight of the 10th.  As in the first minute of the 10th.  To be inclusive of the 10th you either need to add the time (`11:59`) or make it the 11th.

Comment: the date type is TEXT...

Comment: Yikes. That's kind of ... not great for a date. Do you get different kinds of date formats in there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query to select dates between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

Comment: @dgig yeah I know. But I am not the one who designs the db. I don't have the power to change it...

Comment: date type is TEXT **MAKES NO SENSE** do you mean your dates are stored as varchars?

Comment: I understand, it happens. Well, if you do get different date types, you can make them regular dates with DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y')

Comment: @Hogan it is stored as text I guess. I am not the person who designed it. I don't store the data either. My part is to query it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could also just not use `between`.

```
select * from mytable where `date` >= '2014-10-09' and `date` <= '2014-10-10'
```

Example:

```
mysql> create table dd (id integer primary key auto_increment, date text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into dd(date) values ('2014-10-08'), ('2014-10-09'), ('2014-10-10'), ('2014-10-11');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from dd where date >= "2014-10-09" and date <= "2014-10-10";
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  2 | 2014-10-09 |
|  3 | 2014-10-10 |
+----+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Since it includes time, and you dont want the time. this:

```
select substring(date, 1, 10) from dd where substring(date, 1, 10) between '2014-10-09' and '2014-10-10';
```

**question updated again, additional answer**

Ugh. you have timestamp fields? in that case this:

```
select date(from_unixtime(timestamp)) from mytabel where date(from_unixtime(timestamp)) between '2014-10-09' and '2014-10-10'
```

**finally we have arrived at sqlite**

```
select date(datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch')) 
  from mytable 
    where date(datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch')) 
      between '2014-10-09' and '2014-10-10';
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it but I still don't get the data in '2014-10-10'. I think the problem is the date type is TEXT...

Comment: @teelou Then can you please post your table data in the question, because as you can see from the above example, the query works as expected for the dates in a text field

Comment: this answer does the same thing with a datetime type -- you want the OP to cast to Date

Comment: @pala_ the date's data contains time info but I don't want to select the time.

Comment: @teelou so just take the first 10 characters via substring

Comment: @pala_ thanks for the answer. I think the answer of dgig solves my problem.

Comment: @teelou okay. i just added a query that will work for you also - the time portion was the issue but you hadn't mentioned it until just now. Also, you could have mentioned you had timestamp fields

Comment: @pala_ thanks for the update. yeah I have that timestamp fields but I tend to ignore it as they are difficult to decipher without converting them.

Comment: @pala_ mind you. my database is sqlite. so it may be different from mysql. I updated my question.

Comment: that may have something to do with it. i honestly dont know if sqlite supports `from_unixtime`, which is how you work with those sorts of fields in mysql

Comment: `error in statement: no such function: from_unixtime` sqlite is sooooo backward! arg....

Comment: @pala_ yes that works finally! what does 'unixepoch' mean btw?

Comment: @teelou it essentially means unix time - ie, treat the timestamp as seconds since the unix epoch, which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @teelou no problems. i'm guessing at least one of the answers here solved your question so you should probably accept one of them

Comment: Thank you this is the perfect solution +1

Comment: Not using between worked for me (But had to remove time).

Answer (score 27):

IF date is a timestamp, you'll need to do like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytalbe WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-10-09 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-10 23:59:59'
```

Or you can do, I believe:

```
SELECT * FROM mytalbe WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2014-10-09' AND '2014-10-10'
```

Or, since it is a text field:

```
SELECT * FROM mytalbe WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-10-09' AND '2014-10-10'
```

Comment: That second query is the right answer if you add your conversion to a datetime comment from above

Comment: Thanks for the update. I get this error though `Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such function: DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: ... sqlite? why is the question tagged with mysql

Comment: My database is SQLite database. does it make any difference between MySQL?

Comment: @pala_ I thought the querying syntax in sqlite is the same as the mysql. my apologies.

Comment: ah, that I don't know exactly, but appears to be similar - for "date" at least: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: but this works anyway - `SELECT * FROM mytalbe WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2014-10-09' AND '2014-10-10'`

Comment: you could have mentioned from the very beginning that you also had a timestamp field :/

Comment: @teelou, I second pala's comment.  Very frustrating not to see the full picture on what would otherwise be a very simple answer.

Comment: @paqogomez my apologies. I tend to ignore the timestamp fields as they are difficult to decipher without converting them.

Answer (score 2):

same problem solved, thanks.
my code :

```
var FechaInicio = dtpFechaInicial.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var FechaFinal = dtpFechaFinal.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

string SQLcmd = $"SELECT * FROM sorteos WHERE DATE(fecha) BETWEEN ('{FechaInicio}') AND ('{FechaFinal}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code snippet:

```
SELECT local_date FROM (SELECT '2014-10-09 14:59:53' local_date UNION SELECT '2014-10-09 15:01:40' UNION SELECT '2014-10-09 15:02:40') WHERE local_date BETWEEN date('2014-10-09') AND date('2014-10-10')
```

Which basically returned:

```
2014-10-09 14:59:53
2014-10-09 15:01:40
2014-10-09 15:02:40
```

So the query you're looking for is probably this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytalbe WHERE date BETWEEN date('2014-10-09') AND date('2014-10-10')
```

I highly recommend this official documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html