# Date comparison not working when current date is 2 months later to date to compare with

Tags: android, sqlite, date

In my app I have to fetch list of all rows if enrollDate is less or equal to current date .

my SQLite query is as

```
select * from master  where enrollDate<='current date'
```

enroll date in table is `"07/21/2017"` and current date is `"11/22/2017"` .

Everything works well and I get list of rows if current date is till `'30/09/2017'` but when current date start from `"10/01/2017"` then list is returned with 0 rows while its also later date.

Please tell me why it is happening and how to resolve it.

Comment: it right and also working if it is till 09/30/2017, but if it is from  10/01/2017 to current date as 11/22/2017 then 0 rows returned. format is correct

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971871/3395198

Answer (score 1):

You are actually comparing strings, not dates. Strings compare lexicographically.

To compare dates in SQL, consider storing them in a format where lexicographical and temporal ordering are the same. For example, ISO 8601 UTC stamps `yyyy-MM-dd` or Java's `long` epoch milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM master WHERE CAST(strftime('%s', enrollDate)  AS  integer) <=CAST(strftime('%s', currentDate)  AS  integer) ;
```

Comment: thanks to you.but still problem is if I out 07/24/2017 in place of enrollDate then it is returning rows but I put column name here as enrollDate then it is returning 0 rows. kindly help

Comment: can you show me the schema of your table?

Comment: Add some explanation for your answer

Comment: sure did nothing just converted String to seconds and then casted it to integer