# Cannot execute query for Date column using between in SQLite

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I am using SQLITE database in Android.

Create table query is:

```
String CREATE_TBookOrder = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BookOrder (" +
        "  `OrderId` INTEGER ," +
        "  `OrderDate` DATE ," +
        "  `OrderTotal` DOUBLE " +
        ")";
```

I am trying to fetch data between dates using following query:

```
 SELECT OrderId , OrderTotal FROM BookOrder
 WHERE OrderId = 55 AND ( OrderDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-12')
```

But I am receiving zero records in response.

And my code to fetch data is:

```
String queryStr = "SELECT OrderId , OrderTotal FROM BookOrder WHERE OrderId = 55 AND ( OrderDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-12')";
sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queryStr, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Log.d("data", "sub OrderId " + cursor.getInt(0));
        Log.d("data", "sub OrderTotal " + cursor.getFloat(1));
        Log.d("data", "--------------");
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

sqLiteDatabase.close();
```

This runs smoothly on SQL Server but it's not running successfully in SQLITE Android.

Comment: SQLite has not date data type. What are the actual values you're storing in this column?

Comment: I changed the DataType to Text for the OrderDate in Sqlite, still no results

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved It After trying a lot of options.
What Worked for me is ,
first i changed the data type of the date column to DATETIME.
then before inserting the date into the column i converted it into yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss format.

And at the time of retrieving the date i used the following query ,

SELECT OrderId , OrderTotal FROM BookOrder
 WHERE OrderId = 55 AND ( OrderDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-12')

where first Date is Inclusive and second date is Exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the date is stored as a string in the format yyyy-mm-dd then you need to inform the query that you are dealing with dates in the query.

So instead of :-

```
SELECT OrderId , OrderTotal FROM BookOrder
    WHERE OrderId = 55 
        AND ( OrderDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-12')
```

You could use :-

```
SELECT OrderId , OrderTotal FROM BookOrder
    WHERE OrderId = 55 
        AND (date(OrderDate) BETWEEN date('2018-01-01') AND date('2018-12-12'))
```

You may wish to check out [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: I changed the DataType to Text for the OrderDate in Sqlite, 
still no results.

Answer (score -1):

I read your problem, I think there is the issue of the date DataType. Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971762/sqlite-database-select-the-data-between-two-dates/29971871), maybe it solves your problem.

Comment: I changed the DataType to Text for the OrderDate in Sqlite, still no results