# SQLite filter records by part of column value

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime, android-sqlite

**Background:**

Following are the tables that I have:

Persons table:

```
Id      Name
-------------

1       user1
2       user2
```

Orders table:

```
Id      Name        Date                        YearMonth       UserId
----------------------------------------------------------------------

1       item1       2015-11-01 02:34:46         2015-11         2
2       item2       2018-09-06 01:04:16         2018-09         1
3       item3       2018-09-23 04:44:21         2018-09         1
4       item4       2018-09-02 11:10:08         2018-09         2
5       item5       2019-11-01 02:54:02         2019-11         1
```

On the UI side I have defined a spinner for each user which is populated with `YearMonth` column of orders table.
For example for `user1` the spinner would be populated with:

- 2019-11
- 2018-09

I use this query to populate the spinner:

```
 Cursor cursor = db.query("orders",new String[] {"YearMonth"}, "UserId = "+id,
            null, "YearMonth", null, "YearMonth DESC");

// id is a local variable which stores the id of a particular user
```

And whenever I select any of the YearMonth from the spinner all the orders brought on that year and month get returned with this query:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("orders",null,"UserId = ? and YearMonth = ?",
            new String[] {id+"", selectedYearMonth}, null, null, null);

// selectedYearMonth is the value of spinner which is currently selected.
```

**Problem:**

If you notice carefully the column `YearMonth` in orders table is unnecessary I could have done the same with just date column which also mentions the year and month of orders and this is where I want your help.

Can you show me a right way with which I can filter the above queries with part of date column without the need of defining the unnecessary YearMonth column for just filtering the records ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the solution of [@forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas) to best suite the Question:

Modified query for Spinner:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("orders", new String[] {"SUBSTR(orderDate, 1, 7) YearMonth"},
                        "userId = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(personId)},
                        "YearMonth", null, "YearMonth DESC");
```

Modified query of getting orders:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("orders",null,"userId = ? and SUBSTR(orderDate, 1, 7) = ?",
                         new String[] {personId+"", item}, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a column aliased `YearMonth` from the column `Date` by using the function `SUBSTR()`, to get the first 7 chars of the date:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT SUBSTR(Date, 1, 7) YearMonth FROM orders WHERE UserId = ? ORDER BY YearMonth DESC",  
     new String[] {id + ""}
);
```

and your 2nd query will be:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE UserId = ? AND SUBSTR(Date, 1, 7) = ?", 
    new String[] {id + "", selectedYearMonth}
);
```

Comment: Your first query was not ordering and grouping the results I add that in my solution. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Correct, because I forgot the WHERE clause. I edited.

Comment: Still you are missing `group by`

Comment: @Ahtisham why GROUP BY? You are not doing any aggregation. If you want to filter out duplicates then you should use DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

You can query date time with ease, please have a look at [this](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-between/) and [answer relates to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971913/4423647)

```
SELECT
  InvoiceId,
  BillingAddress,
  date(InvoiceDate) InvoiceDate,
Total
FROM
  invoices
WHERE
  InvoiceDate NOT BETWEEN '2009-01-03' AND '2013-12-01'
ORDER BY
  InvoiceDate;
```

Another example

```
SELECT ord_num, ord_amount, ord_date, cust_code, agent_code 
FROM orders 
WHERE ord_date NOT BETWEEN '2008-08-02' AND '2008-30-02';
```

SQLite supports five date and time functions as follows:

- date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
- time(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
- datetime(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
- julianday(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
- strftime(format, timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)

better check how you creating the table, your Date column must be a DateTime field.
hope this helps. give any feedback so I can help you further.