# SQLite-net-pcl Comparing Dates

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, datetime, nuget

As stated in the question I am attempting to do a date comparison for tasks that are done within a specific date range.

My model has a boolean called "Done" and a string that stores dates of completion called "DatesCompleted"

I currently have a query on that shows me all Done items limited to 25 and it works just fine:

```
return db.QueryAsync<Tasks>("SELECT * FROM [Tasks] WHERE [Done] = 1 LIMIT 25");
```

How can I get only dates completed that are 7 days prior to today? This is kind of sudo code how I'd expect to get the solution but I don't know how to write it out in SQLite-net-pcl,

```
return db.QueryAsync<Tasks>("SELECT * FROM [Tasks] WHERE [Done] = 1 AND [DatesCompleted] >= (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(7,0,0,0))` LIMIT 25");
```

Edit:
After attempting the first solution I am having no luck, all items regardless of completion time appear to show up. I tried this:

```
 foreach(var ii in TaskListDoneSource)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ii.Name + " completed on : " + ii.DateCompleted + "  compared against " + (DateTime.Now-new TimeSpan(7,0,0,0)).ToString());
                    if (ii.DateCompleted > (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)))
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The date completed has not quite hit 7 days");

                }
```

The IF statement shows me that it is working when I am within 7 days but outside obviously no IF statement call. So that tells me I'm doing something wrong with the query recommended in first answer:

> SELECT *  FROM [Tasks]  WHERE [Done] = 1 AND [DateCompleted] >=
> datetime('now', '-7 day')

EDIT 2: I got it working with that query provided. Only thing that was off was off was having the DateCompleted as a DateTime instead of a string that was formatted properly in my model. (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite database - select the data between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971762/sqlite-database-select-the-data-between-two-dates)

Comment: It is helpful if I were comparing between specifics but doing datetime.now minus 7 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that in `[DatesCompleted]` you store timestamps in ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, the correct SQLite syntax to get a timestamp exactly 7 days before the current timestamp is:

```
datetime('now', '-7 day')
```

or:

```
datetime('now', '-7 day', 'localtime')
```

to get the timestamp in local time.

so your query should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Tasks] 
WHERE [Done] = 1 AND [DatesCompleted] >= datetime('now', '-7 day')
```

Comment: Odd enough I am still having issues with this solution. 
My code is exactly as you posted :
return db.QueryAsync<Tasks>("SELECT * FROM [Tasks] WHERE [Done] = 1 AND [DateCompleted] >= datetime('now', '-7 day')");
I have it display the completed times in debug when I load tasks page, completed time is right, I change phone system time by a month and still seeing the item from the query that was over 7 days old. It seems like It should be working, not sure whats wrong. I have double checked with: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date-functions/sqlite-datetime-function/ and its same

Comment: I may see what is could be. I just need to confirm. based on that link I just sent, it shows that it is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and my date looks like 4/25/2022 4:28:57 PM