# Find record between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, between

When I write below query it gives record .

```
SELECT [srno],[order_no],[order_date],[supplier_name],[item_code],[item_name],[quntity]
FROM [first].[dbo].[Purchase_Order]
WHERE order_date BETWEEN '22/04/2015' AND '4/05/2015'
```

In this query if I don't add 0 in **'4/05/2015'** it returns record.
But when I add 0 to the date i.e. **'04/05/2015'** it doesn't give any records.

```
SELECT [srno],[order_no],[order_date],[supplier_name],[item_code],[item_name],[quntity]
FROM [first].[dbo].[Purchase_Order]
WHERE order_date BETWEEN '22/04/2015' AND '04/05/2015'
```

Comment: what is your datatype of `order_date`? `date` or `VARCHAR`?

Comment: You can convert it to date type and specifying format rather than depending on in built conversion.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191307.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query to select dates between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: my 'order_date' datatype is 'nvarchar'

Comment: @Pradnya then you should fix that ASAP

Comment: @Pradnya Use proper column types for your data. Just as you wouldn't store a boolean value in a date column, you shouldn't use nvarchar column to store a date.

Comment: **[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)**

Comment: **[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working because SQL is trying to do a string comparison because both your types are string types, But what you really want to do a date comparison.

You should do something like this. Since you only need date part you can strip off the time and use style 103 for your format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(order_date,10),103)
BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'20150422') AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'20150504')
```

Alternately you can use this as well if your `order_date` has dates like this `5/4/2015 03:20:24PM`

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(order_Date,CHARINDEX(' ', order_Date) - 1),103) 
BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'20150422') AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'20150504')
```

A long term solution is to change your column `order_date` to `DATE`/`DATETIME`

Comment: I convert it into DATETIME But also it gives error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Comment: what is the output of this `SELECT TOP 1 order_date FROM Purchase_Order WHERE ISDATE(order_date) = 0`

Comment: Its result is 21-04-2015 03:20:24PM

Comment: Its gives error The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Are all your dates in this format `DD-MM-YYYY `. if the format changes between `DD-MM-YYYY` and `MM-DD-YYYY`, the above your will not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76850/discussion-between-ughai-and-pradnya-bolli).

Answer (score 1):

It Better to Cast it to date rather than depend on **IMPLICIT** conversion

```
SELECT [srno],[order_no],[order_date],[supplier_name],[item_code],
 [item_name],[quntity] FROM [first].[dbo].[Purchase_Order] where 
convert(date,order_date,105) BETWEEN cast('22/04/2015' as Date) AND cast('04/05/2015' as date)
```

Comment: It gives error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: can you tell me type of ORDER_date and Format..??

Comment: Its datatype is nvarchar and format '22-04-2015 04:24:00PM'

Comment: You order_date '22-04-2015 04:24:00PM'  contain Character hence sql cant convert character to date or  datetime ..

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Vary every time because user enter that value

Comment: ohh..!! Than its very Hard to Solve..I personally insist that you should fixed the format of orderdate so you can easily do operation on it.