# How to filter dates in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

I have start date (l_start_date), end date (l_end_date) and dates (l_date) in database.

For an example, User is selecting start date as 15-01-2016 and end date as 30-01-2016. How can I get all the rows of date (l_date) which contains the date between the user selected start date and end date?

I got struck : In the below image (l_date) as 2016-01-29, 2016-01-30, 2016-02-01, 2016-02-02. here how can i get this row too, because user range is till 2016-01-30 but end date (l_end_date) i had stored 2016-02-02 so its ignoring.

[image]

I tried:

```
  SELECT l_date,l_start_date,l_end_date
  FROM `dates`
  WHERE (l_end_date >= '2016-01-15' or l_end_date <= '2016-01-15') AND
        (l_start_date >= '2016-01-15' or l_end_date <= '2016-01-15') AND 
        (l_end_date >= '2016-01-30' or l_end_date <= '2016-01-30') AND
        (l_start_date >= '2016-01-30' or l_end_date <= '2016-01-30')
```

Comment: Seems similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following logic:

```
where l_end_date >= '2016-01-15' and   -- the input start date
      l_start_date <= '2016-01-30'     -- the input stop date
```

The rule is simple.  Two intervals overlap if one starts before the second ends.  And the first ends after the second starts.

For complete overlap, the logic is a little different:

```
where l_end_date >= '2016-01-30' and   -- the input stop date
      l_start_date <= '2016-01-15'     -- the input start date
```

Also note, the inequalities might be strict inequalities ("<" and ">"), depending on how the intervals are defined.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Gordon Linoff explains it very good, but to translate into a context you might understand:

your criteria isn't a criteria at all.

```
(l_end_date >= '2016-01-15' or l_end_date <= '2016-01-15')
```

will return all records, because if the end_date isn't >= it is <= the end date, that's logic. The same goes for the next lines. So you actually don't have a where clause at all. The key word here is **or**.

Try the query provided by @Gordon Linoff

```
 SELECT l_date,l_start_date,l_end_date
  FROM `dates`
  where l_end_date >= '2016-01-30' and   -- the input stop date
      l_start_date <= '2016-01-15'     -- the input start date
```