# Finding daterange in SQL

Tags: sql

Suppose I have two dates

1. 2016-04-16 (yyyy-mm-dd)
2. 2016-05-01(yyyy-mm-dd)

And I want to find birth date that falls between above two dates like birth date between '04-16'(mm-dd) and '05-01'(mm-dd)

Please help me to find this.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're glad to help, but not just do it for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to select dates between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [Between](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE DateOfBirth BETWEEN '2016-04-16' AND '2016-05-01'
```

**UPDATE**
Try this, it'll ignore the year part, using [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    yourtable
WHERE
    CONVERT(varchar(5), DateOfBirth, 110) BETWEEN '04-16' AND '05-01'
```

Comment: it is not fix that year of birth date  = 2016. It may be any year but we can find date from month and day.

Comment: @user3909223 I updated the query, now it ignores the year