# Picking any date from datetime SQl

Tags: sql

I am trying to pick dates in a range april 20 2016 to april 25 2016

```
select * from dates
where svc.last_updated_date > getdate() - .2

Last_Updated_date
2016-04-27 09:22:39.073
2016-04-27 09:22:38.873
2016-04-27 09:22:39.543
```

I want to have dates in between 2016-04-20 to 2016-04-25

```
2016-04-20 09:22:38.873
2016-04-21 09:22:39.543
```

and so on.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I believe this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5125106/6241884

Comment: SQL Server? Which version? Try `where CAST(svc.last_updated_date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2016-04-20' AND '2016-04-25'`