# Birthday reminder for all my users mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a birthday reminder and from here I don't know what to do.
In my MySQL users DB U have birthdate with [month/day/year] And is not working,no error, i updated my bday with this day and still no activity.
This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tbl', 'user', 'pass');
    $today = date("m.d.y");    
    $sqlb = "SELECT `birthdate`, `name`, `surename`  FROM `mls_users` WHERE birthdate = '$today'";               
    $userz = $conn->query($sqlb);

    foreach ($userz as $row) {   
        $name = $row['name'];
        $surename = $row['surename'];
        echo 'Todays is'.$name.' '.$surename.' birthday';                 
    }    
?>
```

Comment: any error are you encounter ?

Comment: can you describe what you are try to accomplish ?

Comment: I want to show on my page birthdates reminders for logged users, similar like facebook for example

Comment: Just checked your comment :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to create an email notification.

```
$mail_content = '';
foreach ($userz as $row) {   
    $name = $row['name'];
    $surename = $row['surename'];
    $mail_content .= 'Todays is'.$name.' '.$surename.' birthday. <br>';                 
}
// send mail to you
// mail code
if($mail_content){
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $mail_content, $headers);
}
```

If you have the users email IDs saved in your Db you can send email to them

```
    foreach ($userz as $row) {   
            $name = $row['name'];
            $surename = $row['surename'];
            //mail code 
            //email message 
            $mail_content = 'Happy birthday '.$name.' '.$surename.' !. <br>';
            $to      = $row['user_email']; //users email field
            $subject = 'the subject';
            $message = 'hello';
            $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            mail($to, $subject, $mail_content, $headers);                       
   }
```

You can automate the script executing process using [CRON Job](http://support.hostgator.in/articles/cpanel/what-are-cron-jobs)

Comment: Thank you epynic for your effort i will use the email sender in this script, but i want the reminder to be shown on the page for all the users, i think has some issues because is not working, i updated my birthdate in db with this day and nothing..

Comment: something wrong with the data formats ? could you tell me the date format in DB ?

Comment: try using  $today = date("d/m/y");

Comment: good, now is working, and now how can i calculate between birthdate and $today?  from (05/07/1986) and today, and shows me that today is my birthday

Comment: if i do : where birthdate < '$today'  is ok?

Comment: Date >= '2011/02/25' and Date <= '2011/02/27'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: Welcome .. Happy coding !