# Access data from database between two dates using sql

Tags: sql

I want to access data from database between two dates, Date format is yyyy/mm/dd. I tried a lot of queries but not succeed.

Comment: Please include the query you attempted and do tell us the database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.).

Comment: Tag the database which you using and show what you've tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to select dates between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query to get data between the range:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table_Name
WHERE   From_date >= '2016-08-01' AND
        To_date   <= '2016-08-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using just vanilla sql it would just be something alone the lines of

```
select x from table where datecolumn between 'xdate' and 'ydate'.
```

Do you have a date column in the table you are looking at correct?