# How can I write sql query to fetch data between start date and end date including records of start date and end date

Tags: sql, database

How can I write sql query to fetch data between start date and end date including records which are created on start date value and end date value as well.
This is my sql query

```
Select * from User where CreatedDate Between '06/06/2017' and '06/09/2017'.
```

But above query result data excluding date '06/06/2017'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to select dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: The standard SQL `between` **does** include the start and end date.  Can you please show your real query and some sample data?

Comment: What is your DB? What is your DateFormat? What datatype is `CreteDate`
 Date or String? Do you include time?

Comment: Use `Column >= Start_Date AND Column <= EndDate` instead.

Comment: It works for me