# To find from a table if there is any nearer date values for the same key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql table (t_accountdetails) with an account column called AccountId and effective date column for that account. An account can have multiple effective date. I have a requirement to get all the entries for the accounts which has very close effective date entries.(an offset of +/-14 days)

Say for eg:

AccountId: 12345 has got 2 entries with effective date 12/11/2017 and 12/18/2017

So my query should return above case where we have an entry of effective dates within offset of +/-14days

Please note I am actually not looking for date +-14 from today. I am looking for effective date which +/- 14 days of another effective date for the same account

Comment: Duplicated question.
Please check <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all records **where exists** another effective date within 14 days, so use `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
select *
from t_accountdetails t
where exists
(
  select *
  from t_accountdetails other
  where other.accountid = t.accountid
  and other.id <> t.id
  and abs(datediff(day, other.effective_date, t.effective_date)) <= 14
)
order by accountid, effective_date;
```

Comment: I am actually not looking for date +-14 from today. I am looking for effective date which +/- 14 days of another effective date for the same account

Comment: Yes, and this is what my query does. Why do you think it deals with today? It compares one record's date (`t.effective_date`) with another record's date (`other.effective_date`).

Comment: I don't have a field called id in my table. ur query has other.id <> t.id

Comment: the query above returns raw if effective date is 01/01/2012 and 01/01/2013 which is not within +/-14 days

Comment: I am using `id` as a record's identifier in order to only look at *other* records and not compare a record with itself. Replace this by the table's ID. If there is none, you could use `effective_date`, but would no longer detect two records with the same `effective_date` (if that is even possible).

Comment: As to  01/01/2012 and 01/01/2013: I guess you have mutilated the query. Removed the ID condition mybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to make it work

```
select * from t_accountdetails where AccountId = 12345 and effectiveDate >= DATEADD(day, -14, getdate()) and effectiveDate <= DATEADD(day, 14, getdate())
```

This will return all records with AccountID = 12345 and an effective date between today - 14 days and today + 14 days. 
Note: if more than one record match the criteria then all matching records will be returned.

Comment: I am actually not looking for date +-14 from today. I am looking for effective date which +/- 14 days of another effective date for the same account

Comment: My bad, I understood the question incorrectly then. The answer from Thorsten Kettner should be doing what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select ad.*
from (select ad.*,
             lag(effective_date) over (partition by accountid order by effective_date) as prev_ed,
             lead(effective_date) over (partition by accountid order by effective_date) as next_ed
      from t_accountdetails ad
     ) ad
where effective_date <= dateadd(day, 14, prev_ed) or
      effective_date >= dateadd(day, -14, next_ed);
```

It would be interesting to compare the performance of this version to the `exists` version with an index on `t_accountdetails(accountid, effective_date)`.

Comment: the query above returns raw if effective date is 01/01/2012 and 01/01/2013 which is not within +/-14 days

Comment: @user2081126 . . . Without sample data, I'm at something of a disadvantage.  But this should only be returning rows where another row is within 14 days in either direction.