# sql select from table with date range condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `tarif` (                  
  `tarif_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_tarif` date NOT NULL,
  `end_tarif` date NOT NULL,
  `day_tarif` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tarif_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `tarif` VALUES (1, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', '10'),
                           (2, '2019-02-11', '2019-02-20', '20'),
                           (3, '2019-02-21', '2019-02-28', '10'),
                           (4, '2019-03-01', '2019-02-10', '15');
```

How can I get `day_tarif` between `2019-02-05` and `2019-02-15` and calculate the `sum = day_tarif * number of date betwwen 2019-02-05 and 2019-02-15`

Comment: It's not a free coding site. Kindly share your efforts first then ask for specific help from others.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name considering the backticks, this is probably MySQL or MariaDB

Comment: What have you already tried? Please share any code you already have written.

Comment: i work with mysql database,i try this SELECT * FROM tarif WHERE start_tarif<='2019-02-15' && end_tarif>='2019-02-05',it work,  but i can't get the  product of  number of day between 2019-02-05 and 2019-02-15 and the value of  day_tarif

Comment: @user3623368 - what is your expected result?

Comment: @user3623368 the second line contains only 5 days until `2019-02-15` (not `2019-02-20`)?

Comment: oh,yes ,i will edit this

Comment: betwwen 2019-02-05 and 2019-02-15 ihave 16day , the first six day are include in the daterange from the first line where day_tarif=10,so the product of six first day mulitiplicate with day_tarif give me 60,the rest of days are includes in the date range from the second line where day_tarif=20,so the product is 20*5=100, the total result must be 160. that is my expected result.and thankyou all for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
SELECT SUM((DATEDIFF(LEAST(`end_tarif`, '2019-02-15'), GREATEST(`start_tarif`, '2019-02-05')) + 1) * `day_tarif`) AS sumCustom
FROM `tarif` 
WHERE `end_tarif` >= '2019-02-05' AND `start_tarif` <= '2019-02-15'
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8dbedb433911b3b4d8c35a9d97d13150)

<strike>You can use the following solution using [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) and [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):</strike>

```
SELECT SUM(`day_tarif`) * COUNT(`tarif_id`) 
FROM `tarif`
WHERE `end_tarif` >= '2019-02-05' AND `start_tarif` <= '2019-02-15'
```

Comment: here you multiply number of day with the sum of tarif_day in the line 1  an line2,that means 11*(10+20)=330. Or we need (6*10)+(5*20)=160

Comment: @user3623368 - You're welcome! Next time try to describe your issue more detailed and with the expected value or result. Many people want to help but only can help (useful) if they unterstand the issue and the expected logic. - [helpful for future questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: now i wont to get number of monday in this rangedate , i run this code but it give me result 0;
select count(*) from tarif where weekday(`end_tarif`<= '2019-02-21'AND `start_tarif`>='2019-02-05') = 0;

Comment: @user3623368 you want to exclude mondays from days count (days count - count mondays)?

Comment: if i have new column contain monday_tarif different from other day_tarif, to calculate global tarif i must specify number of monday and multiply it with mondy_tarif,and the rest of day will be multiply with day_tarif

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUM(day_tarif) * COUNT(tarif_id) 
from tarif
where end_date >= '2019-02-05' AND start_date <= '2019-02-15'
```

This question has been asked several times, or something like it. Be sure to search StackOverflow before asking a duplicate: [SQL query to select dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: now you are missing the `day_tarif` itself in the select list.

Comment: thanks for your  answer, but you have not understand what i want,day tarif is not a date, it's varchar, and i want get it between 2019-02-05 and 2019-02-15, the start date 2019-02-05 contained betwwen start_tarif and end_tarif in the first line,and the end  date 2019-02-15 contained betwwen start_tarif and end_tarif in the second line .that is the problem that i won't solve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
select day_tarif , sum(day_tarif * count (*)) as sum
where start_tarif between '2019/02/05' and '2019/02/15' and end_tarif between '2019/02/05' and '2019/02/15'
group by day_tarif;
```

Comment: thanks, but it dont work,syntaxe error" Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'distinct date )) as sum
where start_tarif between '2019/02/05' and '2019/02/15'' Ã  la ligne 1"

Comment: Can you please translate the error message in English language ?

Comment: syntaxe error near  '*)) as sum
where start_tarif between '2019/02/05' and '2019/02/15' and end_tari'   at line 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code:

```
 WITH cte AS(
 SELECT *
 FROM tablename
 WHERE end_tarif >= '2019-02-05' AND start_tarif <= '2019-02-15'
 )
 SELECT day_tarif, day_tarif * COUNT(tarif_id) AS 'SUM'
 FROM cte
 group by day_tarif;
```

Comment: sample data shows that `start_tarif` should be associated with lowest_Date value and `end_tarif` with highest_date value. What do you say?

Comment: Hi @MuhammadWaheed, thanks for bringing it to my attention! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you are after...

```
Declare @tarif as table (                  
  tarif_id int NOT NULL ,
  start_tarif date NOT NULL,
  end_tarif date NOT NULL,
  day_tarif varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @tarif VALUES (1, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', '10'),
                           (2, '2019-02-11', '2019-02-20', '20'),
                           (3, '2019-02-21', '2019-02-28', '10'),
                           (4, '2019-03-01', '2019-02-10', '15');

-- Declare parameters
Declare @paramstart date, @paramend date
Set @paramstart='2019-02-05'
Set @paramend='2019-02-15'

-- Set up loop
Declare @mincount int, @maxcount int, @myval int, @curstart date, @curend date,@curtarif int, @mytarif int

Set @mincount=(Select MIN(tarif_id) from @tarif where  end_tarif >= '2019-02-05' AND start_tarif <= '2019-02-15')
Set @maxcount=(Select Max(tarif_id) from @tarif where  end_tarif >= '2019-02-05' AND start_tarif <= '2019-02-15')
Set @mytarif=0


-- Do loop
WHile @mincount<=@maxcount
BEGIN

Set @curstart=(Select start_tarif from @tarif where  tarif_id=@mincount)
Set @curend=(Select end_tarif from @tarif where  tarif_id=@mincount)
Set @curtarif=(Select cast(day_tarif as int) from @tarif where  tarif_id=@mincount)

IF @paramstart between @curstart and @curend 
    BEGIN
    Set @mytarif=@mytarif+((DATEDIFF(day,@paramstart,@curend)+1) * @curtarif)
    END

IF @paramend between @curstart and @curend 
    BEGIN
    Set @mytarif=@mytarif+((DATEDIFF(day,@curstart,@paramend)+1) * @curtarif)
    END

IF @paramstart not between @curstart and @curend  and @paramend not between @curstart and @curend
    BEGIN
    Set @mytarif=@mytarif+((DATEDIFF(day,@curstart,@curend)+1) * @curtarif)
    END

Set @mincount=@mincount+1
END

Select @mytarif as tarif
```