# sql query related issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have one more question in want to the user between the operator in php. This is my SQL query.

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_id,day,activity,hotel 
FROM wp_user_activity 
WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND date BETWEEN $start AND $end ");
```

it gives me an error

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_id,day,activity,hotel 
FROM wp_user_activity 
WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND date BETWEEN '26/05/2019' AND '31/05/2019' ");
```

am getting data in this why in the $start and $end am not getting any data

Comment: can you show your both `$start` and `$end` values?

Comment: date is a keyword. Surround the fieldname with ticks i.e. \`date\`. Also the date should be in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to select dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: Can you check the phpmyadmin (database) structure of your 'date' filed ?

Comment: actually the $start date and $end dates both coming from another table where i have stored the date which i took from postman in varchar.

Comment: i will show you how i store date in database 26/05/2019 , in this way the date is stored

Comment: Format your dates before using it in your sql query. $StartDate = date("Y-m-d",$start) and $EndDate = date("Y-m-d",$end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your date format is wrong
please use standard date format that is YYYY-MM-DD
Use this

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_id,day,activity,hotel 
FROM wp_user_activity 
WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND date BETWEEN '2019-05-26' AND '2019-05-31' ");
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: issue is that when i used between operater with in one month i mean 01/05/2019 to 31/05/2019 i works but when i used 31/05/2019 to 06/06/2019 it returns me empty array but i have data of 31/05/2019 and 02/06/2019 and 03/06/2019

Answer (score 0):

try the following to see your SQL then review :

$sql = "SELECT user_id,day,activity,hotel FROM wp_user_activity WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND date BETWEEN $start AND $end ";

echo $sql;
exit;

Comment: "SELECT user_id,day,activity,hotel FROM wp_user_activity WHERE user_id = '1' AND date BETWEEN 0.0025755324418029 AND 0.0030708271421496 "

Comment: i tried am getting this but my start date in 26/05/2019 and end date is 31/05/2019

Comment: See the thing is that i want to delete woocommerce_persistance_cart cart has been delete successfully but when i refresh database same data appears again.

$user_id=$data['user_id'];

global $woocommerce;

get_user_meta($user_id,'_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1',true);

delete_user_data($user_id,'_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1'); 
i want to delete cart and it should not come again if i delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working. $arr=array(); foreach($results as $single) { $start = $single->trip_start_date; $end = $single->trip_end_date; /* return $sql = "SELECT user_id,day,activity,hotel FROM wp_user_activity WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' "; */ $results=$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_id,day,activity,hotel FROM wp_user_activity WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' "); $single->trip_details=$results; $arr[]=$single;

}

Comment: am unable to post question so that is why am asking here i have groci theme in which i have to clear cart but an unable to clear cart it reappears again in data base . i used get_user_meta($user_id,'_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1',true);
 return delete_user_meta($user_id,'_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1');