# Query data between the same date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
select * from table where Date BETWEEN '2019-05-29' AND '2019-05-29'
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `where Date ='2019-05-29'`

Comment: Already answered in this [question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: I suspect a different question along the lines of I want a general query on date range where sometimes the date range will be the same date.

Comment: This assumes that the datatype of `Date` is `DATE`!  If it is `DATETIME`, then you are checking only for midnight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. If you have time part you could use [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to skip it:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(Date) BETWEEN '2019-05-29' AND '2019-05-29'
-- it may degrade performance, condition is not SARGable
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the better approach is:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.Date >= date('2019-05-29') AND 
      t.Date < date('2019-05-29') + interval 1 day
```

Why is this better?  It doesn't have a function on the column name, so it can make use of an index on the `date` column.

Comment: The use of `date()` is optional in this context.

Comment: Furthermore, this phrasing handles whatever datatype `Date` is, including, for example, the microsecond-resolution `DATETIME(6)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, if you want to run it in a test window without manually changing the date within the code you can set it as a variable. Use trunc to get rid of time i.e there will be no 29-05-2019 23:59:00. If you want the same date within a time period remove the trunc and then you can set hours-minutes-seconds which makes your query more precise

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.date BETWEEN trunc(to_date(:datefrom, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) AND
                     trunc(to_date(:dateto, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Comment: Looks more Oracle than mysql.