# get sql date between

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2005, sql-date-functions

I want to get data from a range of selected dates in SQL Server.

This is the SQL query (SQL Server 2005)

```
SELECT  * FROM  slips WHERE  CONVERT(char,  date_Of_Birth, 101)  BETWEEN ('01/08/2019') AND ('21/08/2019')
```

It gives me a results of every record on my database, how do I get selected range? I want only the selected range to show.

Comment: SQL questions not declaring the database system in use are like language questions hiding the language in question. Mostly broken. (Looks like you mean MS SQL Server.)

Comment: You've learnt an unhelpful rule (don't worry about it, everyone does at some point) that you can make things work if you just treat everything as strings. Unfortunately, that rule only really exists if you define "work" as "compiles and runs without raising language errors". It rarely works if you want correct results. The solution is to work in the other direction - get all of your data, variables, etc to use the *correct* data types. That way things like comparisons can use *that type*'s rules, rather than the string rules.

Comment: @fhulufhelohanyahanya What is the datatype of column **date_Of_Birth**

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil im using nvarchar. i changed my date format from M/d/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy and its no longer getting selected range

Comment: @fhulufhelohanyahanya then you should the second query i have posted in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `between` with dates.  [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is a good explanation of why not.

Also, do not use string comparisons for dates.  SQL Server has lots of nice built in date functionality.

I would recommend:

```
select s.*
from slips s
where s.date_of_birth >= '2019-08-01' and
      s.date_of_birth < '2019-08-22'
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your **date_of_birth** is date type then you need to convert your **string** to **date**

```
SELECT  * FROM  slips WHERE  date_Of_Birth  BETWEEN CONVERT(date,  '01/08/2019', 103) AND CONVERT(date,  '21/08/2019', 103)
```

if your **date_of_birth** is **string** type the you shoud use this

```
SELECT  * FROM  slips WHERE  CONVERT(date,  date_Of_Birth,103)  BETWEEN CONVERT(date,  '01/08/2019', 103) AND CONVERT(date,  '21/08/2019', 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BETWEEN` with dates ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates))

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM slips 
WHERE date_Of_Birth BETWEEN '01/08/2019' AND '21/08/2019'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the slips in last N months - Replace N with Months

```
Select *
FROM slips 
Where DATEDIFF(MONTH, date_of_birth, GETDATE()) Between 1 and N
```

If you want to select the slips in last N days  - Replace N with days

```
Select *
FROM slips 
Where DATEDIFF(DAY, date_of_birth, GETDATE()) Between 1 and N
```

If you want to select the slips in last N years -  - Replace N with Year

```
Select *
FROM slips 
Where DATEDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, GETDATE()) Between 1 and N
```