# Select two tables between dates?

Tags: c#, sql-server, between

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '2020-05-29'.

How to fix this?

```
SELECT Borrower.BorrowedDate, BorrowerDetails.DueDate 
FROM Borrower, BorrowerDetails 
WHERE Borrower.BorrowedDate BETWEEN '2020-05-28' AND BorrowerDetails.DueDate '2020-05-29'
```

Comment: Use correct  syntax for the `WHERE` clause - `WHERE Borrower.BorrowedDate BETWEEN '2020-05-28' AND '2020-05-29'`. Also consider using an unambiguous date format and correct casting `WHERE CONVERT(date, Borrower.BorrowedDate) BETWEEN '20200528' AND '20200529'`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with two columns in your between clause? Try to create your statement with greater/lesser ( > / < )instead of between.

Comment: I want between table1.From and table2.To

Comment: Be sure to read [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) as well

Comment: You can't use between for that. And you should be using proper joins.

Comment: @Zhorov that format is unambiguous. I assume BorrowedDate is a date type, making your convert superfluous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query to select dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`BETWEEN` doesn't work in that format. You need to change your data format or use epoch time for these dates.

```
SELECT Borrower.BorrowedDate, BorrowerDetails.DueDate
FROM Borrower, BorrowerDetails
WHERE Borrower.BorrowedDate >= 20200528
AND BorrowerDetails.DueDate <= 20200529;
```

Don't forget to remove single quotes . We are comparing it like numbers , not like strings.

Comment: Sure it does work with original format too (it may depend on connection language however).

Answer (score 0):

`Between` doesn't seem to support two fields.

You may use:

```
SELECT Borrower.BorrowedDate, BorrowerDetails.DueDate 
FROM Borrower, BorrowerDetails 
WHERE Borrower.BorrowedDate >= '2020-05-28' AND BorrowerDetails.DueDate <='2020-05-29'
```

Comment: Doesn't seems is an under statement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. The sql syntax is clear.