# SQL query does not return correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to filter between two dates on a SQL server from a PHP process.

This is the query:

```
select *
from webStocks
where FECHAMODIFICADO between '2020-06-03 17:16:02' and  '2020-06-04 17:16:03'
ORDER BY webStocks.FECHAMODIFICADO DESC
```

This is the result:

[image]

The result is not what I want. In the table I have the following information and it should be the result.

[image]

What am I doing wrong in the query?:(

Comment: I think the data is the same, just in a different ordering.  You haven't specified an `order by` so rows with the same date can be in any order.

Comment: perhaps you find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to make sure the date column actually contains 'timestamp' data type.

If it doesn't, the following code should fix it:

`SELECT *
FROM webStocks
where CAST(FECHAMODIFICADO AS timestamp) BETWEEN '2020-06-03 17:16:02' AND  '2020-06-04 17:16:03'
ORDER BY webStocks.FECHAMODIFICADO DESC`

You can see more information about this kind of statements [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp).
(this solution is valid mostly for MySQL, but will probably work with either CAST or CONVERT statement with other SQL servers).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, instead of timestamp I have put date, since the column is of type datetime

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  That means that when you run a query with no `ORDER BY`, the results can be in any order -- and even in different orders on different runs.

In this case, you have an `ORDER BY`.  But the column has duplicates.  The same principle applies:  rows with the same key value can be in any order -- and even in different orders on different runs.

So, you need to add a new key to capture the order that you want.  It is not obvious from your data.  But the results would at least be stable if you used:

```
ORDER BY webStocks.FECHAMODIFICADO DESC, CodeArticulo
```

It is also odd that your `WHERE` clause includes very specific times.  But the data in these rows is all occurring at midnight.  Usually midnight is not such an active time, if the time stamps represent human behavior.