# Not SELECTING data between two dates that are from different months in SQLite

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to write [XLSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Current_file_extensions) from an SQLite table with a *WHERE* clause between two selected dates.

Below is my example:

```
search_from = "19-09-2020"
search_to   = "19-10-2020"

conn=sqlite3.connect('project.db')
writer      = pd.ExcelWriter("data.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
data = "SELECT Pro_ID, Pro_Name, Pro_City FROM table WHERE `Started_Date` >= ? and `Started_Date` <= ?"

df_data         = pd.read_sql(data, conn, params=(search_from, search_to))
df_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Data")
```

It is selecting data if search_date and started_date are the same month, but not if they are in different months.

Comment: use BETWEEN - refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: Use only dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD for SQLite tables and compare them to date strings of the same format and your code will work fine.

Comment: @ forpas Actually for now i want to use DD-MM-YYYY. and If i use YYYY-MM-DD this is my above query fine or  is any modification required ?

Comment: And Is it work for years also if YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: SQLite stores dates as TEXT (strings) so use only the format YYYY-MM-DD in the table and for the parameters that you pass: search_from = "2020-09-19" and search_to   = "2020-10-19"

Answer (score 0):

Date strings need to converted into a valid date format for SQLite as below:

```
from dateutil import parser

search_from = "19-09-2020"
search_to   = "19-10-2020"

search_from = parser.parse(search_from, parser.parserinfo(dayfirst=True))
search_from = search_from.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

search_to = parser.parse(search_to, parser.parserinfo(dayfirst=True))
search_to = search_to.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then, you can update your query as below using *between*:

```
query = "select Pro_ID, Pro_Name, Pro_City from table where Started_Date between search_from and search_to"
```

Or you can use:

```
query = "select Pro_ID, Pro_Name, Pro_City from table where Started_Date >= search_from  and Started_Date <= search_to"
```

Of course, you need to bind variables to a SQL query. In your case:

```
data    = "select Pro_ID, Pro_Name, Pro_City from table where Started_Date between ? and ?"
df_data = pd.read_sql(data, conn, params=(search_from, search_to))
```

Or:

```
data    = "select Pro_ID, Pro_Name, Pro_City from table where Started_Date >= ? and Started_Date <= ?"
df_data = pd.read_sql(data, conn, params=(search_from, search_to))
```

Comment: Why do you expect strftime() and between to work? What is it that makes your 2nd query *exclusive*?

Comment: In order to format the date string. For instance > search_from = "19-09-2020"

Comment: strftime() formats only valid dates YYYY-MM-DD. For a date like 19-09-2020 it returns null. Also strftime() with the `%s` modifier does not format even valid dates. Read about it: https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: @forpas Thanks for the comment. I have updated the answer based on that.

Comment: @ forpas and @ ozturkib. Thank You for your response. @ozturkib is required to use `from dateutil import parser` for both queries? And in second query, is no need to use Quotation mark?

Comment: Yes, you need to format date string properly for sqlite needs, parser part is handling this side. So you need it in your scenario.

Comment: @ozturkib I tried Above answer, both queries not working.

Comment: @Mano you should not directly copy and paste them, you need to bind them for your case. However, I have updated the answer which takes into account binding as well.

Comment: @ozturkib. I did not do copy past. I bind them in to my query before your update then only i commented. still not working. Also I changed `s_search_from` to `search_from`  tried as like your update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223684/discussion-between-ozturkib-and-mano).